# Adding Cloudinary Pod in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, cloudinary

I'm using Cocoapods for installing 3rd Party Frameworks. My project is in Objective-C Code. I'm using around 10+ Pod frameworks with Cocoapods. But now I couldn't install **Cloudinary** in my Project.

This is what i have given in my Podfile: `pod 'Cloudinary, (~> 2.0)'`

My app has deployment target as 8.0. Even cloudinary have the same minimum deployment target. As I know, Cloudinary depends on Alamofire. Even I tried with New sample project, it won't installing. When I try to installing, it throws an error like below.

> Cloudinary (~> 2.0) required by `Podfile` Specs satisfying `Cloudinary (~> 2.0)` dependency were found, but they required higher minimum deployment target"

I just checked with deployment target dependency. But it matches with my project.

Anyone have come across this problem ?  Any solutions ?

//UPDATE

Screenshots of Pod update after changed to

> platform :ios, '9.0'
>   [image: Pod update errors][image: Pod update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the problem why Cloudinary is not installing with CocoaPods. I have QMServices (QuickBlox) in my Podfile. I hope this framework is compatible with use_frameworks!. Cocoapods won't allow the installation of Cloudinary with this pod.

When I removed QMServices from the Podfile, Cloudinary can be installed properly with iOS 9.0.

However, I still don't know which particular dependency causes the problem in between Cloudinary and QMServices.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Cloudinary's SDK (v2.0.1) actually currently supports iOS 9+ (as for writing these lines), they'll need to update it (they can support iOS 8).

If you want to keep supporting iOS 8 you have several options, the easiest on your part would be using Cloudinary's swift-2.3 branch, since it supports iOS 8:

```
pod 'Cloudinary', :git => 'https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios.git', :branch => 'swift-2.3'
```

But you'll have to remember to change it once Cloudinary updates their master branch to support iOS 8, since this branch is a temporary support brach for swift-2.3 and will probably not get any updates.

You can also remove Cloudinary from your Podfile and add Cloudinary as a submodule, then set its target to iOS 8.

Comment: I changed minimum deployment target to 9.0 and then did pod update. But still getting the same error as there in question.

Comment: I'm using xCode 7.3 for this project itself. Since, it is developed without autolayout, Storyboard files will rearrange if i open with xCode 8.1

Comment: You can't use the master branch on Xcode 7, use the swift-2.3 branch like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: How can i add Swift framework in my Podfile when i already having 10+ Objective C pod frameworks. When i update both, it throws error. @Oferm

Comment: The master branch was written in swift as well, it doesn't matter in this case, the framework supports ObjC.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan, you can have 2 versions of xcode installed on your computer, and use one to open storyboard files, and the other for everything else.  As long as you don't open the storyboard files themselves inside of xcode 8, they won't be modified.